# Is there is a way to merge only for certain column in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my Requirement.
1)First we should compare the first two rows ,first column is duplicates then it should get merged.2)I want to merge columns for first two columns and last two columns ,only if first column is same, if it is not same then it should not get merged 3)Then the color should be in white and grey,if the same row is duplicates then it should be same color of the parent row

Here Column is been merged and the table color is in white and grey,if the same color is duplicate then that color should be repeated.

```
<style>
   table {
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
  }

th {
background: #a9a9a9;
 }

 td,
 th {
border: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
padding: 8px;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 17px;
}

.dark {
background-color: #dddddd;
  }
    </style>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    <th>Col4</th>
    <th>Col5</th>
     <th>Col6</th>
     <th>Col7</th>
     <th>Col8</th>
     <th>Col9</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
     <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
     <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germanyindgo</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>aa</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>aaaa</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>bb</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>bbbb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>cc</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
    <td>cccc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
            <td>d</td>
            <td>dd</td>
            <td>ddd</td>
            <td>dddd</td>

  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
            <td>e</td>
    <td>ee</td>
    <td>eee</td>
    <td>eeee</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 1</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli 1</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>ff</td>
    <td>fff</td>
     <td>ffff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 1</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli 2</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>ff</td>
    <td>fff</td>
     <td>ffff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 3</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli 3</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>ff</td>
    <td>fff</td>
    <td>ffff</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
     </table>
 </body>
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    const previousRow = {};
      const colsChanged = {};
     let leftMerged = false;
    let dark = false;

         Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).forEach((tr, rowIdx) => {
       Array.from(tr.children).forEach((td, colIdx) => {
  if (rowIdx > 0 && (colIdx === 0 || leftMerged) && 
      previousRow[colIdx].text === td.innerText) {
    previousRow[colIdx].elem.setAttribute('rowspan', 
    ++previousRow[colIdx].span);
    colsChanged[colIdx] = false;
    td.remove();
    if (colIdx === 0) {
      leftMerged = true;
    }
  } else {
    previousRow[colIdx] = { span: 1, text: td.innerText, elem: td, dark };
    colsChanged[colIdx] = true;
  }
});
const rowChanged = Object.values(colsChanged).every(Boolean);
dark = rowChanged && rowIdx > 0 ? !dark : dark;
if (dark) {
  tr.classList.add('dark');
}
leftMerged = false;
   });
  }
```

Now i want to apply merge for only certain columns ,For eg: I want to  merge for first three columns and the last two columns not for the entire table, only if the two rows first column is same

```js
function myFunction() {
  const previousRow = {};
  const colsChanged = {};
  let leftMerged = false;
  let dark = false;

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).forEach((tr, rowIdx) => {
    Array.from(tr.children).forEach((td, colIdx) => {
      if (rowIdx > 0 && (colIdx === 0 || leftMerged) && previousRow[colIdx].text === td.innerText) {
        previousRow[colIdx].elem.setAttribute('rowspan', ++previousRow[colIdx].span);
        colsChanged[colIdx] = false;
        td.remove();
        if (colIdx === 0) {
          leftMerged = true;
        }
      } else {
        previousRow[colIdx] = { span: 1, text: td.innerText, elem: td, dark };
        colsChanged[colIdx] = true;
      }
    });
    const rowChanged = Object.values(colsChanged).every(Boolean);
    dark = rowChanged && rowIdx > 0 ? !dark : dark;
    if (dark) {
      tr.classList.add('dark');
    }
    leftMerged = false;
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background: #a9a9a9;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
         <th>Col6</th>
         <th>Col7</th>
         <th>Col8</th>
         <th>Col9</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germanyindgo</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>bb</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>cc</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>dd</td>
                <td>ddd</td>
                <td>dddd</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
                <td>e</td>
<td>ee</td>
<td>eee</td>
<td>eeee</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 1</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli 1</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>ff</td>
        <td>fff</td>
         <td>ffff</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 1</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli 2</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>ff</td>
        <td>fff</td>
         <td>ffff</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 3</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli 3</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>ff</td>
        <td>fff</td>
        <td>ffff</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding an array to hold the indices of the columns to merge:

```
const colsToMerge = [0, 1, 7, 8];
```

and then change the first `if` to also check if the column index is in the array:

```
if (rowIdx > 0 && (colIdx === 0 || leftMerged) &&
    previousRow[colIdx].text === td.innerText &&
    colsToMerge.includes(colIdx))
```

That way, only the columns 0, 1, 7 and 8 will get merged it there are adjacent cells.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const previousRow = {};
  const colsChanged = {};
  const colsToMerge = [0, 1, 7, 8];
  let leftMerged = false;
  let dark = false;

  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr')).forEach((tr, rowIdx) => {
    Array.from(tr.children).forEach((td, colIdx) => {
      if (rowIdx > 0 && (colIdx === 0 || leftMerged) && previousRow[colIdx].text === td.innerText && colsToMerge.includes(colIdx)) {
        previousRow[colIdx].elem.setAttribute('rowspan', ++previousRow[colIdx].span);
        colsChanged[colIdx] = false;
        td.remove();
        if (colIdx === 0) {
          leftMerged = true;
        }
      } else {
        previousRow[colIdx] = { span: 1, text: td.innerText, elem: td, dark };
        colsChanged[colIdx] = true;
      }
    });
    const rowChanged = Object.values(colsChanged).every(Boolean);
    dark = rowChanged && rowIdx > 0 ? !dark : dark;
    if (dark) {
      tr.classList.add('dark');
    }
    leftMerged = false;
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background: #a9a9a9;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Col4</th>
        <th>Col5</th>
         <th>Col6</th>
         <th>Col7</th>
         <th>Col8</th>
         <th>Col9</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germanyindgo</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>aaaa</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>bb</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>bbbb</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>cc</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>cccc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
                <td>d</td>
                <td>dd</td>
                <td>ddd</td>
                <td>dddd</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
                <td>e</td>
<td>ee</td>
<td>eee</td>
<td>eeee</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 1</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli 1</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>ff</td>
        <td>fff</td>
         <td>ffff</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 1</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli 2</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>ff</td>
        <td>fff</td>
         <td>ffff</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti 3</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli 3</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>f</td>
        <td>ff</td>
        <td>fff</td>
        <td>ffff</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for that @jo_va